# Dynamically typecast from a function that returns a Class

Tags: objective-c

```
    - (void)activate:(NSDictionary *)options {
      Class c = [self displayClass];
      self.display = [[c alloc] initWithOptions:options];
      (c *)self.display.delegate = self;
```

My display property is of a base Display class.

Error on the last line. The delegate in question is only available to the current displayClass which is a sub-class of Display.

How do I cast to set the delegate?

EDIT:

I understand that (Display *) works. I am trying to make the ((Display *) part dynamic. When I do     (c *)self.display).delegate = self; I get "Expected expression".

Comment: You can set just one class as the base class, include all common properties (like delegate) and subclass from this to any other class. Then typecast to the base class, which is clean as well.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're assuming a couple of custom methods here (`initWithOptions` and `delegate`). These can be unsafe to call without first checking that those methods exist. I would recommend creating a protocol and checking that your class conforms to it before initing your display object.

```
@protocol MYDisplay //use whatever prefix you want here

@property (readwrite, weak) id<MYDisplayDelegate> delegate;
- (id) initWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)options;

@end
```

Then, in your activate method, check that this is a valid class to use and cast to an instance of that protocol.

```
- (void)activate:(NSDictionary *)options 
{
      Class c = [self displayClass];
      if ([c conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MYDisplay)])
      {
          id<MYDisplay> display = [[c alloc] initWithOptions:options];
          display.delegate = self;
          self.display = display;
      }
      else
      {
          NSLog("Can't create a display from class %@", NSStringFromClass(c));
      }
}
```

Each of your Display classes will then need to adopt this protocol.

```
@class SomeConcreteDisplayClass : NSObject <MYDisplay>

@property (readwrite, weak) delegate;
- (id) initWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)options;

...

@end
```

You can also [extend UIKit classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) to make them conform to this protocol if you're mixing and matching your own custom classes and framework classes for use as your Display objects

You can check a lot of similar things about NSObject and classes. Take a look at the "Obtaining Information About Methods" in the [NSObject class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I understand it's unsafe to call without checking -- that's why I'm trying to typecast. @suresh's answer is close to what I want to do. I just want the (Display *) portion to be *dynamically* loaded from a function.

Comment: Typecasting is not going to make that any safer. In Objective-C, you can cast any ivar to any other class and the compiler will do it, you'll just get a runtime exception if the call fails. If you're only interested in suppressing the compiler warning, you can cast to `id`. So, `((id)(self.display)).delegate = self;`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your superclass name is `Display` from your question. Try the following code.

```
- (void)activate:(NSDictionary *)options {
      Class c = [self displayClass];
      self.display = [[c alloc] initWithOptions:options];
      ((Display *)self.display).delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: I understand that works. I am trying to make the ((Display *) part dynamic. When I do     (c *)self.display).delegate = self; I get "Expected expression"

Comment: You can give a try : [self.display setObject:self forKeyPath:@"delegate"]

Comment: that will work. But how could I dynamically cast where the class is from a function?

Comment: I am not sure, but try NSClassFromString.